# How many moles of methyl iodide will be consumed by one mole of crixivan?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

[image: This question is from the National Standard Examination in Chemistry, India, 2019]

My take on this question : a total of 5 moles of $\ce{CH3I}$ should be consumed.

1. The oxygen atoms in the $\ce{2 OH}$ groups each have a lone pair of electrons. They should displace $\ce{I-}$ from methyl iodide via an $\ce{S_N2}$ reaction.
2. The two nitrogen atoms in the tertiary amino moieties also should react with a total of 2 moles of $\ce{CH3I}$ .
3. The $\ce N$ atom in the pyridine moiety should also consume a mole, as the lone pair of electrons on it is not in conjugation with the benzene nucleus.

However, as I checked the answer, it's provided as 3. What may be the fallacy in my reasoning?

Comment: The OH groups will not methylate without being deprotonated first, there is no base present strong enough to do this.

Comment: Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms". It makes it even worse seeing this on the picture of a textbook question. I am sad now.

Comment: Why so? A mole of CH3I is equal to a gram equivalent of CH3I.